# What does it mean if an Azure AKS cluster does not have zone awareness?

Tags: azure, azure-aks

If an AKS cluster is created without zone-awareness (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/availability-zones#create-an-aks-cluster-across-availability-zones), what does this mean behind the scenes?

Are all the VMs running behind running in 1 of the 3 available availability zones?

When that zone has an outage, will Azure move the cluster to another AZ that is running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that control plane components might (or will?) be in a single availability zone:

> If you don't define any zones for the default agent pool when you
>   create an AKS cluster, the AKS **control plane components** for your
>   cluster will not use availability zones. You can add additional node
>   pools using the az aks nodepool add command and specify --zones for
>   those new nodes, however **the control plane components remain without
>   availability zone awareness**.

emphasis is mine. so this means even if your worker nodes will be up, your cluster won't work properly, because master nodes are down.

And no, it won't get moved to another availability zone in case of the outage